# How to Upload Image into SQL Server using api

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am trying to upload an image with user data into a PHP SQL server using laravel API..

but I am getting error on uploading image..

My Image Code is:

```
var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
  'image',
  image.readAsBytes().asStream(),
  image.lengthSync(),
  filename: image.path.split('/').last,
);
```

Error I am getting Is :

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MultipartFile'
```

I have also tries to upload image directly without multiparts but still getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class ApiHelper {
  imageUpload(File imageFile) async {
    var stream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    var length = await imageFile.length();

    var uri = Uri.parse(uploadURL);

    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length, filename: basename(imageFile.path));

    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it says: The method 'basename' isn't defined for the type '_HowWillUseState'. (Documentation)